Read CSV - There should be a unique row for each daily entry combining health metrics and supplement usage
Can you help me with the interpretation of this sentence ?

Does this mean you should group by date rows with different supplement usage?

Or should I have 2 rows, one for magnesium and one for placebo?

If I have 2 experiments/2 different supplements taken the same day, then this means one entry?


Screenshots of output I have:

EDIT: I also have this detail in the exercice. For me it means that we can have multiple entries in the same 'cell'/field supplement_name   The name of the supplement taken on that day. Multiple entries are permitted.
Days without supplement intake should be encoded as 'No intake'.
Edit 2: schema


can you please explain what is the input and the expected output, I am not sure what the ask is ?
You can read this article about how to format a question =>https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

The input is 4 tables that I have to merge using pandas.
I will add a schema

add sample input data, add sample output data, dont use image , you should add sample dataset
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

I think sensibly interpreting the requirement requires some knowledge of how they data will be used. Presumably they're not asking you to group unrelated users together, and combine daily entries that happened on the same day. But if it's an exercise for the sake of an exercise, then maybe they're asking for something that doesn't make sense.
